# Some product pages show different theme - why?

Tags: layout, xml, ce-1.9.2.2

I have inherited a site to finish that is proving to be difficult. There is a specific set of product pages that are not inheriting the theme set in the admin panel. I have checked all of the layout.xml files and nothing is set there. I have switched themes to make sure it's not theme-specific, and the issue remains. I installed CommerceBug, turned on profiling, you name it.

I looked through the list of options n98-magerun offers and noticed database logging. Turned that on and checked the output when I finally got a hit. See below:

```
SQL: SELECT `layout_update`.`xml` FROM `cart1_core_layout_update` AS    `layout_update`
 INNER JOIN `cart1_core_layout_link` AS `link` ON link.layout_update_id=layout_update.layout_update_id WHERE (link.store_id IN (0, :store_id)) AND (link.area = :area) AND (link.package = :package) AND (link.theme = :theme) AND (layout_update.handle = :layout_update_handle) ORDER BY `layout_update`.`sort_order` ASC
BIND: array (
  ':store_id' => '2',
  ':area' => 'frontend',
  ':package' => 'default',
  ':theme' => 'contest',
  ':layout_update_handle' => 'THEME_frontend_default_contest',
)
```

For reference, this is what it looks like for other pages:

```
SQL: SELECT `layout_update`.`xml` FROM `cart1_core_layout_update` AS `layout_update`
 INNER JOIN `cart1_core_layout_link` AS `link` ON link.layout_update_id=layout_update.layout_update_id WHERE (link.store_id IN (0, :store_id)) AND (link.area = :area) AND (link.package = :package) AND (link.theme = :theme) AND (layout_update.handle = :layout_update_handle) ORDER BY `layout_update`.`sort_order` ASC
BIND: array (
  ':store_id' => '2',
  ':area' => 'frontend',
  ':package' => 'ultimo',
  ':theme' => 'default',
  ':layout_update_handle' => 'default',
)
```

I have no clue where those values are being set. I've checked the `core_layout_link` and `core_layout_update` tables but they are empty. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the Design tab within the product edit screen? If it's not in the default scope, check the design tab within the scope of your store view.

Comment: Yeah. That was actually the first place I checked. I should've noted that in my initial description. Thanks Shawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value `THEME_frontend_default_contest` comes from `loadLayout()` in the controller action. By default, Magento loads the `default` layout handle as well as a `STORE_{store_id}` and `THEME_{area}_{package}_{theme}` handle.

So this log is just evidence that the current theme is "default/contest" but it does not explain, why.

If it's really not a custom layout update in the product configuration, it's probably something in custom code.

Next step: Search for "contest" in `app/code` and in the `core_config_data` database table.